# Magnetic power connectors (ie. "dots") for slim power supply connection

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, mechanical

This may be more of a mechanical question, but does anyone know what these magnetic power connectors are called?  You see these on Fitbits and other IoT devices.

I'm building an IoT board, that has a waterproofing requirement so a USB connector is out.

Typically there are these magnetic "dots" insert molded in a plastic enclosure, and then the DC adapter has a custom molded connector with matching "dots" that magnetically link to the unit.

Here is a image from a device that has the "dots" I am talking about.

Is there a name or manufacturer/s that are selling these pieces off-the-shelf, for designing electronics with these magnetic "dots"?

I'm thinking someone must sell a premade cable, like USB male end to "dots" on the other end, that you can put in a USB female end wall wart.

[image]

Comment: [magnetic+pogo+pins](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1371&bih=834&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=magnetic+pogo+pins).

Comment: Boom goes the dynamite.  Thanks, that's EXACTLY what I was looking for!

Comment: I don't know of any USB cables that use magnetic pogo pins for the USB-male connector, but there are a number of micro-USB cables where the male micro-USB connector uses magnetic pogo pins.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for [magnetic+pogo+pins](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1371&bih=834&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=magnetic+pogo+pins).

[image]

*Figure 1. One of many types available.*

Answer (score 3):

Don't immediately discard a convenient usb connector, there are [several waterproof options](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=waterproof%20micro%20usb&safe=off&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNvuaBo5HXAhUN92MKHZumCywQ_AUICSgA&biw=1366&bih=662&dpr=1) out there.

[image: One of many types available.]

Comment: I am using a similar waterproof connector, but without USB...